# How to know the treadmills are enough or not?

Tags: excel

I'm doing an analysis of a gym and want to know if we should get more treadmills or not.

The running history record contains the users `name`, `start time`, `end time` and `duration`.

My idea is to use a pivot table in Excel, put the start date and time into the row, and the sum of duration in the value, the right click on the time, click group, by hour, then the duration will be the sum for each hour from morning to evening.

If the sum of duration of each hour is close to 120 mins for 2 treadmills, it means it's full.

But if people run over the hour, for example, from 1:30pm to 2:30pm, the duration will all count to 1-2pm, so it's not correct.

Does anyone have a good method?

Thanks

Here is some sample data

```
name                 sex  device id  device type  start date  start time   end date  end time  duration(mins)  distance(km)  Calorie
Emmie Aguila      Female       a001    Treadmill   2020-7-25     9:34:18  2020-7-25  10:20:20              46           4.5    338.6
Dusty Gorham      Female       a002    Treadmill   2020-7-25     9:13:45  2020-7-25   9:49:02              35           3.1    192.2
Diann Lafreniere  Female       a001    Treadmill   2020-7-25     9:12:06  2020-7-25   9:33:27              21           2.1    142.6
Rima Hoop           Male       a001    Treadmill   2020-7-25     7:10:10  2020-7-25   7:30:14              20           2.4    230.8
```

[my pivot result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6zno.jpg)

Comment: Is the running history kept for 24 hours, or longer?

Comment: Did you try the method you proposed? What were the problems you occured?

Comment: the running history kept for weeks.

Comment: as I said, the duration will be treat as the hour when user start, so the result no I supposed( the duration should not more than 120 mins for 2 treadmills)

Comment: Break your problem down into small segments. First develop a matrix where you have the usage for each hour and each day. This can be done with worksheet formulas, VBA or Power Query.  I don't believe it can be done with a Pivot Table from your raw data as shown above.  Then decide how you want to summarize the data: Maximum, Average or some other parameter that perhaps includes the Frequency of different levels of usage.  Then manipulate your hourly data to present your report.

Answer (score 0):

One of mine friend find a solution for Excel.

1. Convert start/end time to seconds, for example, 0-3600 for 0-1am, 3600-7200 for 1-2pm
2. Get the overlap time length by comparing the duration with each hour.

> ```
> > name    sex     mobile      device-id   device-type start date  starttime    endtime                duration(mins)  distance(km)    calorie Start–sec   end-sec 3600    7200    10800   14400   18000   21600   25200   28800   32400   36000   39600   43200   46800   50400   54000   57600   61200   64800   68400   72000   75600   79200   82800   86400
> > Emmie   Female  1.23412E+11 a001        Treadmill   2020-7-25   9:34:18     2020-07-25 10:20:20     46              4.5             338.6   34458       37220   0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       1542    1220    0       0       0       0  0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0    0
> ```

(I tried many times but last few zero digits can not align correctly)

1. convert time to seconds
   starttiem(H3) -> start-sec(M3)

   =HOUR(H3)*3600+MINUTE(H3)*60+SECOND(H3)

endtime(I3) -> end-sec(N3)

```
=HOUR(I3)*3600+MINUTE(I3)*60+SECOND(I3)
```

2.compare the duration with each hour in secods

```
=IF(OR(O$1>$N3, $M3>O$2), 0, MIN($N3, O$2)- MAX($M3, O$1))
```

Apply the fomula for whole sheet, then the data is ready.

Create a pivot sheet, drag the date into the row, all the hour seconds(1-24) into column, we can see the result clearly by creating a bar chart.
[usage for treadmills for each day](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ss92I.jpg)